# Left outer join of 2 datatables

Tags: c#, linq

I want to left join 2 data tables `AllTimesTxnTable` and `resolvedDt` in C#, Where I want every row from AllTimesTxnTable and only matching rows from resolvedDt.

The join condition should be based on `mid` and `txndate` and finally while selecting **I want mid and txndate from AllTimesTxnTable and txncount from resolvedDt, if no record in resolvedDt then a 0.**

I tried the following LINQ query:

```
 var results = from table2 in AllTimesTxnTable.AsEnumerable()
               join table1 in resolvedDt.AsEnumerable()
               on new { mid = table2.Field<int>("mid"), txndate = table2.Field<string>("txndate") } equals new { mid = table1.Field<int>("mid"), txndate = table1.Field<string>("txndate") }
               into temp
               from leftTable in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select new
               {
                    MId = (int)table2["mid"],
                    TxnDate = (string)table2["txndate"],
                    TxnCount = leftTable["txncount"] == null ? 0M : (decimal)leftTable["txncount"]
                };
```

But it gives me an Error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` while selecting.

Not getting whats going wrong here.

Comment: Your question is in danger of being closed as duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) famous question.

Comment: will the stack trace help?

Comment: have you at least used the debugger to ensure that the datatables you are using aren't null at this point?

Comment: Yes. Both the datatables contain data.

Comment: inside the `select`, you need to check `leftTable` (which in fact is a right table in a join) for `null`. This is typical for outer joins.

Comment: @IvanStoev: got the issue. Thanks for the suggestion. Working on fixing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated the code. Its working now.

```
var results = from table2 in AllTimesTxnTable.AsEnumerable()
              join table1 in resolvedDt.AsEnumerable()
              on new { mid = table2.Field<int>("mid"), txndate = table2.Field<string>("txndate") } equals new { mid = table1.Field<int>("mid"), txndate = table1.Field<string>("txndate") }
              into temp
              from row in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new
              {
                   MId = (int)table2["mid"],
                   TxnDate = (string)table2["txndate"],
                   TxnCount = row == null ? 0M : (decimal)row["txncount"]
              };
```